# setState cause Invariant Violation addComponentAsRefTo

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm using `react-rails` with `Fluxxor` and `React`. My component is fully functional as long as I stay on the same page.

However, if I change the page by clicking on an other link and come back to my component, when I try to use `setState` on it, It throw the error :

```
Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's `render` method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.
```

My actual code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-besnard/e78989803a7210b9a0b2). The problem seems to be the `setState` method [here](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-besnard/e78989803a7210b9a0b2#file-hashtagpriority-js-jsx-L73). Maybe the `refs` attribut of my `Chosen` component can't be re-render ? May it be caused by `Turbolink` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a problem in the implementation of the `Chosen` component.

When it's given new props, React re-renders it and puts new nodes in the page. However, `$.fn.chosen` has already been instantiated, and it's attached to DOM nodes that aren't in the page anymore. I suspect that, somewhere along the way, references to old nodes and components are being preserved, even after they're unmounted.

I had the same problem using `select2` with React. I found Ryan Florence's guide to jQuery + React to be very helpful:

> We need a way to stop rendering with React, do the jQuery dialog work, and then start rendering with React again. Some people call these "Portals". You open a portal for React to skip over a bit of old-school DOM stuff, and then keep going on the other side.
>
> The big trick is rendering nothing and then calling React.renderComponent inside a component.
>
> ```
> var Dialog = React.createClass({
>   render: function() {
>     // don't render anything, this is where we open the portal
>     return <div/>;
>   },
>   componentDidMount: function() {
>     var node = this.getDOMNode();    
>     // do the old-school stuff
>     var dialog = $(node).dialog().data('ui-dialog');
>     // start a new React render tree with our node and the children
>     // passed in from above, this is the other side of the portal.
>     React.renderComponent(<div>{this.props.children}</div>, node):
>   }
> });
> ```

source https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md